# Changing Image to another Image in Resources folder (VisualStudio 2015 / c#)

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2012, resources

I'm trying to change the Background Pic of a Button to another Pic that I saved in the Resources Folder. Currently The Code is the following (FinalDStagePickBANNED.png being the Pic I want it to change to):

```
private void FinalD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BanFDButton.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(FinalDStagePickBANNED.png);
}
```

The Thing is, that it apparently finds no Pics in the Resources-Folder, although there are like 10 pics.

---

Solved: The solution to the problem was to put the FinalDStagePickBANNED into quatation-signs, and to remove hte .png ending.

Comment: Though I don't know much about your surrounding code, it *feels right* to put `FinalDStagePickBANNED.png` in quotes.

Comment: YES!
Thanks, apparently your feeling was right!
I also had to change FinalDStagePickBANNED.png into FinalDStagePickBANNED (Had to remove the.png ending"

Anyway, thank you! :D